# Trying to load 4 lines of code from txt file into a rich textbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, windows-forms-designer

This is my code. I have a richTextBox and I loaded a txt file into it. I have a combobox that shows the name of the employee. What im trying to do is make the rich textbox load 4 lines of text from the txt file when a record is selected from the combobox. The code from everything works except getting the 4 lines of text.

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("employeeData.txt"))  `
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)    
    {
        reader.ReadLine();     `

        numLines = employeeDataRichTextBox.Lines.Count();

    }
    employeeDataRichTextBox.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: In your specific code you are not reading the lines. In any case you could store them in a string builder.

Comment: You can do it with a one-liner: `employeeDataRichTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadLines("employeeData.txt").Take(4));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are consuming the lines before setting them to the textbox, so nothing will be added.

Change the code to this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("employeeData.txt")) 
{
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
          employeeDataRichTextBox.Text += reader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: I cant get it to work for other if statements. (var i = 4; i < 8; i++) When I set the code to this its not working? How should I skip the first 4 lines.

Comment: You must consume first the four lines, so do first a loop from 0 to 4 which only reads the lines and don't assign them to the tb, and then do other from 0 to 4 which reads the lines to the tb. The numbers at the for loop donesn't influence at all the read from the stream, it's sequential.

Answer (score 0):

`reader.ReadLine()` reads current line and then advances to next line. Your code reads 4 lines but doesn't put them into any variable. Then, when the reader is on the fifth line, you are telling him to read from that line to end.

add varialbe outside the `for` loop

```
List<string> listOfLines = new List<string>()
```

modify

```
reader.ReadLine();
```

into

```
listOfLines.Add(reader.ReadLine());
```

and finally put those lines into textbox

```
employeeDataRichTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, listOfLines.ToArray());
```

Comment: It says streamreader does not contain a definition for .Readline

Comment: oh, come on. It is `ReadLine()`, with capital L and brackets. It isn't so hard to modify code. Try to understand code, not just copy/paste solution.

Comment: It was a typo on my part only for that comment. I followed  his solution and tried to get it working and if your not going to bother helping don't bother to add a comment.